# Redactor: Apply class name(s) to uploaded images

Tags: redactor, redactor.js

I know I can get access to it and apply a class (or whatever) dynamically after a successful upload of an image in Redactor however, I need to give the user the option to add a css class to any image she/he requires.

Using Redactor's formatting API is not an option as it only allows for certain tags to be formatted. From their docs:

> formattingAdd can only be applied to p, pre, blockquote and header
>   tags.

I also could not find a way to get into their image modal for when you click "Edit" that appears on an image on hover. Would it be possible to place a dropdown (or any html control) in that modal and retreive its value to manipulate the image tag that is being edited?

Any help, idea or an answer from somebody who had same/similar requirement before, would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing up my own plugin. I would not mind it, if I did not paid for this thing but you cannot get tech support even if you have purchased the thing. Because of this there is literally nothing on the internet you can find from other users around the web since there are tons of other editors on the web that does similar, if not identical, functionality..

IF YOU COME ACCROSS THIS POST AND IF IT IS NOT TOO LATE, GO FOR A FREE WYSIWYG EDITOR SO YOU CAN FIND ENOUGH SUPPORT TO YOUR PROBLEMS FROM OTHERS!